# Recurisvely iterate through nested Map[String, Any]

Tags: scala, recursion

I have an arbitrarily nested `Map[String, Any]` that I want to traverse and update values given a certain path.

For example, if the nested `Map` is

```
Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> Map("c" -> "2"))
```

and the path is `["b", "c"]` I expect the result to be

```
Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> Map("c" -> "null"))
```

What I've tried so far is

```
def updateMapValue(
                map: Map[String, Any],
                path: List[String]
              ): Map[String, Any] =
map map {
  case (k: String, v: String) =>
    if (k.contains(path.head)) k -> "null"
    else k -> v
  case (k: String, v: Map[String @unchecked, _]) => updateMapValue(v, path.tail)
}
```

but the compilation error I get here is

```
Expression of type Iterable[Equals] doesn't conform to expected type Map[String, Any]
```

which happens when I try to call `updateMapValue` recursively.

What is happening here and is there an easier way to traverse nested `Map`s?

Comment: I would start by, why do you have a nested `Map[String, Any]` in the first place. Usually that means you had a bigger problem upstream. Specially in these cases, I always think that you probably are dealing with some kind of **JSON** or other recursive structure. Have you looked at libraries that already handle these problems on a more _typesafe_ way. For example: [**Circe**](https://circe.github.io/circe/).

Comment: To give more context, the `Map[String, Any]` comes from a Spark `DataFrame` column that is of type `MapType` and there is no fixed schema (each row can have a different schema). I will look into encoding the `Map[String, Any]` object into a JSON object that I can then more easily traverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several problems with your code. First of all, you're using `head` which would throw an exception in the case, there is no head on path list (and it would happen if you passed the wrong path to the method).

Secondly, here `case (k: String, v: Map[String, _]) => updateMapValue(v, path.tail)`
 you're returning map, with wrong type, you probably meant `k -> updateMapValue(v, path.tail)`.

Here's my implementation:

```
def updateMapValue(
                    map: Map[String, _],
                    path: List[String]
                  ): Map[String, _] = {

  path match { //we iterated over path getting head
    case x :: xs => map.map {
      case `x` -> (m: Map[String, _]) => x -> updateMapValue(m, xs) //if value is map go deeped
      case `x` -> (_: String) => x -> "null" //if value is String replace with "null"
      case w => w
    }
    case Nil => map
  }

}


val m = Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> Map("c" -> "2"))
val path = List("b", "c")
updateMapValue(m, path) //Map(a -> 1, b -> Map(c -> null))
```

This method is not stack-safe, because it's not tail-recursive, but if you know your maps won't be very deep it should do the job.
You can make it stack-safe with *TailCalls* though.